# how can i create a new database base on a sql script

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-scripts

I have generate a "schema only " database script for my staging database, using sql server 2008 r2 . now i need to execute the script to create the same database including (table, column, keys, etc) inside the production server. so my question i how i can execute the script inside the production server.

Second question; currently i have generate the script to include only the schema, but i have some look-up tables which i need to move its data from staging to production. so my question is how i can generate a script that copy the schema or the whole database , and also copy the data for specific tables ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your first question :

you have to create your data base manualy if your scrip have only tables shema and open new query window and run it

for your second question :

from sql server managment studio you have to do Generate script in Tasks then choose your tables then in Advanced there's `Type of data script` you have to shoose Schema only or data or Scema with data

More explanation

I found [this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/) to explaine generate script, and in the window of `Choose Object` you can select `Select specific database objects` and select only the tables you want

Comment: can you explain your second point , so is there a way to have my database script including data for certian tables only?

Comment: in this link it will copy the data for all the tables , while in my case i need to copy the data for the lookup table only ..

Comment: @johnG and in the window of Choose Object you can select Select specific database objects and select only the tables you want

Comment: @johnG with Choose Object you have to view all tables and select only the tables you want to generate

Comment: in my case i need to generate the Schame-only for all the tables , and the data for the look-up tables only ..

Comment: then you have to generate 2 script, the first with all tables (Schema Only) and the second script for only look-up tables (with DataOnly)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47740/discussion-between-akrem-and-john-g)